# Why does registered delegate fire when token not canceled?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I am trying to understand using CancellationTokens and listening for them.  I found examples that shows how to register a listener, however it still fires off even when the process is not canceled.

My calling test method:

```
    private static void TestRun2()
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();  
        try
        {
            var options = new ParallelOptions
            {
                CancellationToken = cts.Token,
            };

            Parallel.Invoke(options,
                () => TestMethod(cts.Token));

            cts.Cancel();
            cts.Dispose();

        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
        {
            cts.Cancel();
            cts.Dispose();
            Console.WriteLine("Timeout");
        }
    }
```

The method in question with the CancellationToken registered:

```
    private static void TestMethod(CancellationToken token)
    {
        var wc = new WebClient();
        wc.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("GetWebData: Request completed.");

        // Cancellation on the token will
        // call CancelAsync on the WebClient.
        token.Register(() =>
        {
            wc.CancelAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("GetWebData: Request cancelled!");
        });

        Console.WriteLine("GetWebData: Starting request.");
        wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.microsoft.com"));
    }
```

It appears to work when I force a cancellation... however when I don't the delegate still gets called and i get notification on the console what the request was cancelled.  I have looked around but not seeing any explanation as to why i would continually see this happening.

So the question is why is it showing request cancelled when it wasn't cancelled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take a look at this:

```
Parallel.Invoke(options,
    () => TestMethod(cts.Token));

cts.Cancel();
cts.Dispose();
```

You fire off `TestMethod`. TestMethod is asynchronous. It will return *immediately*. Then immediately after that, you signal for a cancel by calling `cts.Cancel()`.

It's working as designed. Change your callback to this:

```
wc.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
    Console.WriteLine($"GetWebData: Request completed. Cancelled: {e.Cancelled}");
```

It will output:

```
GetWebData: Request completed. Cancelled: True
```

To better illustrate my point, try doing this:

```
Parallel.Invoke(options,
    () => TestMethod(cts.Token));

Thread.Sleep(5000);

cts.Cancel();
cts.Dispose();
```

Obviously, you shouldn't do this in your final implementation, it's just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: I made the first change.... and yep it showed true... then added the thread.sleep and the e.cancelled showed false, but the delegate still fired off.... GetWebData: Request cancelled!".  So I my next question is do I need to do the cts.cancel?  Leaving cts.dispose seems ok.

Comment: @Kixoka -- You registered a callback on the CancellationTokenSource to fire off when it's cancelled. That will always show no matter what state the download is in.